# how to change getWritableDatabase() pointing path?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this code:

```
// 2. get reference to writable DB
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

and I see db is

`SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.myApp/databases/user.db`

however another part of my app writes to here:

`adb pull data/data/com.myApp/user.db`

( i verified pulling with `adb pull`)

How can i change the path of `SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.myApp/databases/user.db`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/data/data/com.myApp/databases/user.db` is a correct location for databases. Consider fixing the part of your code that expects it to be `data/data/com.myApp/user.db`.

To change the path, you can supply a full path to `SQLiteDatabaseHelper` constructor instead of just the database name `user.db`.

Comment: like this? `super(context, /data/data/com.myApp/databases/user.db, null, DATABASE_VERSION);`

Comment: Yes, with `"quotes"`. But don't assume the path is always like that. There are devices where it isn't. Best not to specify a path at all; second best to use `context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir`

Comment: i get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File data/data/com.MyApp/user.db contains a path separator`